# Rails strong parameters datetime picker correct format for database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, strong-parameters

As a somewhat beginner programmer, this problem has bugged me for years. I have a jquery datetime picker that fills in a form field with a date formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY` aka `06/27/2015`. Databases won't seem to save the date unless it comes in the `YYYY/MM/DD` format. But, despite how my database feels, I like this format because users know how to read it.

So I've got a date in the wrong format when it comes over to my controller. I could use strftime to edit the date before saving it. But I'm lazy in a way, because still want to use strong parameters to create my entry like so.

```
def create
  Statistic.create(statistic_params)
end
def statistic_params
  params.require(:statistic).permit(:entry_date)
end
```

What's the best way to adjust the date format so the database recognizes it and keeps my users happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Statistic model, you can change the `entry_date` attribute using the [`before_save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) method which will let you change the attribute before saving to the database, so that you don't need to worry about strong parameters.

```
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :set_entry_date

  def set_enty_date
    self.entry_date = DateTime.strptime(self.entry_date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
  end

end
```

Comment: I can't seem to get access to `entry_date` in the model when I pass it in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Also, I think I'd need to use `strptime`. I'm still using strong parameters because I also have 15 other attributes to save. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you validating the entry_date, because if validation fails, before_save won't be called. I'm editing the answer anyway. Also I guess you are right with the formatting time.

Comment: Let me play around with this a little bit tonight and let you know. Thanks for your help on this.